# Max width with twitter bootstrap label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve similar thing as SO with tags.

It looks [great](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5991/), but the problem is that I want to have a maximum width of each tag, so if a the length of the the tag, is too big, it will be truncated.

I can achieve it with:

```
.label{
    width: 50px;    
    float: left;    
    overflow: hidden;  
}
```

Ok, it works, but when I do this, my number is [not on the same line as label](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5990/).

How can I achieve the same effect as on the first fiddle, but with maximum width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should to do the trick:

```
.label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

## [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5995/).

What I've done here is dropped the `float: left` and replaced it with `display: inline-block`. I've then given it an ellipsis `text-overflow` property to make it look nicer, and set the `vertical-align` to `middle` to get it in line with the `.multiple` element. Oh, and I've replaced `width` with `max-width` to stop smaller tags being the same size.

#### Example Usage

Here is an example with multiple tags (each are on a new line intentionally): [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5997/).

[image: Example]

Obviously you can adjust the `max-width` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can give

```
 float:left;
```

to span.multiple as well so the span and label come in the same line.

```
.multiple{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add line-height to both of them

```
.label, .multiple {
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jr6f/) link.

Answer (score -1):

```
.label{
   max-width: 150px;    
   float: left;    
   overflow: hidden;  
 }
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It is the same thing that I just told that it does not work.